# Return err view is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller that has a return type of void. Is there any way which I can redirect this controller to an error view page?

I try many things but its not worked for me like create error page and return it like
return View("Error");

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use the following:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect
```

Good luck!

Shimi